# I'm trying to add a new user to my mysql server, but there was a syntax error occured. ERROR 1064(42000)

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL, and I'm trying to add a new user to the server and give the rights of SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE to this user. There are the code I entered:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO user
       (host, user, password, select_priv, insert_priv, update_priv)
       VALUE('localhost', 'guest', 
       password('guest123'), 'Y', 'Y', 'Y');
```

And the error occured:

```
ERROR 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '('guest123'), 'Y', 'Y', 'Y')' at line 4
```

After that, I have tried to change the code, delete "password" in line 4 like this:

```
       'guest123', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y');
```

But it still goes wrong:

```
ERROR 1054(42S22):Unknown column 'password' in field list
```

My MySQL server version is 8.0.13 MySQL Community Server, Please help.

Comment: You have a column 'user' in your table 'user', I'd guess this is causing problems but I can't be sure. At the very least it's bad practice, try changing that column name

Comment: Perhaps check the documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html which may help you out.

Comment: You shouldn't add users by updating the table directly, you should use the `CREATE USER` command.

Comment: @J2112O I do solve this problem after visit the link you gave, thanks.

Comment: @KC.Kelvin glad that helped. Barmar is correct as well, which is why I referred you to the documentation.